# Get Count for the answer of the below query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Can somebody guide me how to get the count for the answer of this query?

```
SELECT      wo.Client_id
FROM        wish_order wo, 
            wish_order_fruit wof
WHERE       wo.wish_order_id = wof.wish_order_id 
GROUP BY    wof.wish_order_id 
HAVING      Count(wo.Client_id) > 1;
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do. You're using `GROUP BY` in a way that's hard to understand. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: the answer of this query is as following:

Comment: Client_Id
________ 
6 
7 
2
I need the count of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table to get the # of rows returned by the group by query

```
select count(*) from (
    select wo.Client_id
    from wish_order wo, wish_order_fruit wof
    where wo.wish_order_id = wof.wish_order_id 
    Group by wof.wish_order_id 
    having Count(wo.Client_id) >1
) t1
```

Comment: @user3693592 it's the name of the derived table